# Glassfish - Font file and stylesheets and gzip

Tags: gzip, glassfish

We used to use Tomcat but are migrating to Glassfish 4 for our application server.

We are trying to enable compression, but for some reason, when we do, `woff` and `ttf` files are aborted.  No errors, no response, just aborted (according to Firebug).  The second issue with this is that when you click the refresh button on the page, the stylesheets and javascript files are requested and then aborted, exact same way as the font files on the initial load.

Now if I force reload (shift+refresh) it will request the `css`/`js` files and it loads them perfectly.  The font files are still requested and aborted.

Both HTTP listeners have compression `on` and the types set to `"text/html,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/json,image/png,image/jpeg"`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to go with this?  If you want to try out what I stated, the website is http://ko2.keyboardingonline.com/.  I can give you more config info if you need it.

Comment: Tim, are you trolling us? ;) Works for me. Receiving all resources.

Comment: I figured it out just now.  Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to leave my answer up instead of deleting it, just in case some one in the future has the same question.  Turns out the problem was Glassfish 4.  We downgraded to the latest stable version of 3 and it works flawlessly with the same compression settings.  Sorry for making it look like I was trolling, we reverted about an hour or so after I posted this.  I guess for now we will stick with Glassfish 3, and maybe when 4.1 comes out we will upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this issue is related to a bug in Glassfish 4. Check out the link bellow:
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20726